# Перевод в обратную польскую запись

Tags: c++, алгоритм, стек

Проблема в отображении символов(знак + - * /)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int pror(char c){
    int p;
    switch (c)
    {
    case '(':
        p = 0;
    case ')':
        p = 1;
    case '+':
    case '-':
        p = 5;
        break;
    case '*':
    case '/':
        p = 4;
        break;
    case '^':
        p = 2;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return p;
}


class stackSTR {
private:
    int size, top;
    char a[100];
public:
    stackSTR() { top = 0; }
    void push(char var) {
        a[++top] = var;
    }
    char pop() {
        return a[top--];
    }
    char see() {
        return a[top];
    }
};

int main(){
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    stackSTR stk;
    cout << "Enter your ... " << endl;
    string q, w, tmp;
    cin >> q;
    for (int i = 0; i < q.length(); i++) {
        if (!isdigit(q[i])) {
            if (stk.see()==0) {
                stk.push(q[i]);
            }
            else if((pror(q[i])>=stk.see())) {
                if (q[i] == ')') {
                    while (stk.pop() != '(') {
                        w += stk.pop();
                    }
                    stk.pop();
                }
                else {
                    stk.push(q[i]);
                }
            }
            else {
                while (stk.pop() != 0) {
                    w += stk.pop();
                }
            }
            
        }
        else {
            w += q[i];
            cout << w << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << w << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Код реализован почти правильно. Но некоторые вещи написаны "неаккуратно". К примеру, нет функции проверки того, что стек пуст (для этого почему то проверяют, что в стеке ноль, а его туда никто не ставил специально). Также, в самом конце нужно извлечь из стека все, что там осталось, иначе выражения вида `1+2+3` будут неверными. И последнее - в стеке сравниваются приоритеты. А у Вас приоритет текущего и символ. Тоже очень странно. Вот минимально поправленный код, похоже, что он работает нормально (я пробовал на нескольких примерах)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int pror(char c){
    int p;
    switch (c)
    {
    case '(':
        p = 0;
    case ')':
        p = 1;
    case '+':
    case '-':
        p = 5;
        break;
    case '*':
    case '/':
        p = 4;
        break;
    case '^':
        p = 2;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return p;
}

class stackSTR {
private:
    int size, top;
    char a[100];
public:
    stackSTR() { top = 0; }
    void push(char var) {
        a[++top] = var;
    }
    char pop() {
        return a[top--];
    }
    char see() {
        return a[top];
    }
    bool empty() { return top == 0;}
};

int main(){
    stackSTR stk;
    std::cout << "Enter your ... " << std::endl;
    std::string q, w, tmp;
    std::cin >> q;
    for (int i = 0; i < q.length(); i++) {
        std::cout << q[i] << "\n";
        if (!isdigit(q[i])) {
            if (stk.empty()) {
                stk.push(q[i]);
            }
            else if((pror(q[i])>=pror(stk.see()))) {
                if (q[i] == ')') {
                    while (stk.pop() != '(') {
                        w += stk.pop();
                    }
                    stk.pop();
                }
                else {
                    stk.push(q[i]);
                }
            }
            else {
                while (!stk.empty()) {
                    w += stk.pop();
                }
                stk.push(q[i]);
            }
        }
        else {
            w += q[i];
            std::cout << w << std::endl;
        }
    }
    while(!stk.empty()) {
        w += stk.pop();
    }
    std::cout << w << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

дальше самостоятельно

Comment: Спасибо большое